# How to use the `Ninject.Extensions.Factory` to dynamically generate factories for internals classes?

Tags: ninject, factory, internal, castle-dynamicproxy, ninject-extensions

I need to use the `Ninject.Extensions.Factory` to generate the constructor of internal classes. Follow one example:

```
using Ninject.Extensions.Conventions;
using Ninject.Modules;
using Ninject.Extensions.Factory;

namespace ClassLibrary
{
    using System;

    namespace ClassLibrary
    {
        internal class Class1
        {
            public void Print(string message)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(message);
            }
        }

        internal interface IClass1Factory
        {
            Class1 Create();
        }

        public interface IInterface2
        {
            void PrintMessage();
        }
        internal class Class2 : IInterface2
        {
            private readonly IClass1Factory _class1Factory;

            public Class2(IClass1Factory class1Factory)
            {
                _class1Factory = class1Factory;
            }

            public void PrintMessage()
            {
                Class1 class1 = _class1Factory.Create();
                class1.Print("Class2's IInterface2 'PrintMessage' implementation.");
            }
        }

        public class MyNinjectModule : NinjectModule
        {
            public override void Load()
            {
                Kernel.Bind(r => r
                .FromThisAssembly()
                .IncludingNonePublicTypes()
                .SelectAllClasses()
                .BindAllInterfaces());

                Kernel.Bind<IClass1Factory>().ToFactory();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Application using the library:

```
using ClassLibrary.ClassLibrary;
using Ninject;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel();
            kernel.Load<MyNinjectModule>();
            IInterface2 interface2 = kernel.Get<IInterface2>();
            interface2.PrintMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

Even after include `[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo(InternalsVisible.ToDynamicProxyGenAssembly2)]` I'm getting the following run tine error:

> {"Type 'Castle.Proxies.IClass1FactoryProxy' from assembly
>   'DynamicProxyGenAssembly2, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null' is attempting to implement an inaccessible
>   interface.":""}

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: You probably just didn't quote it right, but the correct diction of `InternalsVisibleTo` is `[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("DynamicProxyGenAssembly2")]`, not `[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo(InternalsVisible.ToDynamicProxyGenAssembly2)]`

Comment: Thanks a lot @BatteryBackupUnit! That solve the problem. I was just doing what the first exception message suggest me (the exception when you don't put any `[assembly: ]` at all suggest add `[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo(InternalsVisible.ToDynamicProxyGenAssembly2)]` instead of `[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("DynamicProxyGenAssembly2")]`) Seem to me that DynamicProxy have that message outdated, I will file a bug when I have time to avoid others people fall in this trap like me ;) Thanks again. PS If you need create an answer for this question I will select it as the right answer.

Comment: The difference is that the `ToDynamicProxyGenAssembly2` constant has the strong name public key token. What version of Castle Core are you using? The message was improved in 3.2.1: https://github.com/castleproject/Core/issues/30

Comment: @JonathonRossi Thanks, in fact I was using the version 3.2.0. That is the version that get installed as dependency of the [Ninject.Extensions.Factory](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Ninject.Extensions.Factory/) package.